# Using javascript functions in a Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this sounds weird but i have tried to create a function that checks a variable before executing the remaining jQuery code, it looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myVar = true;

    var myFunction = function(){
        if (myVar) {
            // do something
        };
    };

    $("div").click(function(){
        myFunction();
        $("div).fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

I guess this is not how you implement a function in jQuery so i am a bit lost.

Comment: `$("div).fadeOut("fast");` Syntax error, after div need `"`

Comment: Well you forgot the closeing `"` after div. I don't know if that is a typo or your problem. If that isn't the issue, what errors are you getting? We need more detail than that

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. You don't write *in* jQuery, you write JavaScript *with* jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a double quote in your click handler:

```
$("div").fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div).fadeOut("fast");
```

Syntax error

replace it

`$("div").fadeOut("fast");`